# Android. ToggleButton и иконка

Tags: android, вёрстка

Привет! Можно ли в ToggleButton поместить иконку сразу по центру, как это происходит в ImageButton при добавлении иконки через android:src?
В ToggleButton с помощью android:drawableTop/Bottom/Left/Right/Start/End иконка помещается в кнопку отодвинутой к какому-нибудь краю, и приходится сдвигать ее к центру с помощью android:padding.

Comment: Вы можете использовать стили для размещения иконки на ToggleButton
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6100438

Comment: да, окей, спасибо!